# Online CRC-32 calculator result is incorrect, wrong polynomial?

Tags: png, crc32, chunks

I have to say that I don't really understand the mechanics of CRC-32; but I was hoping to be able to at least calculate a CRC based on a chunk.

```
I have a PNG with the following information: 2px by 5px, RGBa, no interlace
The image header chunk results in:
00 00 00 0d = data is 13 bytes long
49 48 44 52 = ascii for IHDR (image header)
00 00 00 02 00 00 00 05 08 06 00 00 00 = data; dimensions, bit-depth, etc.
6f b3 3d 9c = CRC
```

I wanted to see if CRC could be easily calculated so I tried using:

```
http://depa.usst.edu.cn/chenjq/www2/wl/software/crc/CRC_Javascript/CRCcalculation.htm
```

The calculator's default polynomial for CRC-32 is 04C11DB7.

```
When I plug in "0000000d4948445200000002000000050806000000" I get 35F0A255.
```

I looked it up on Wikipedia and tried the other various representations used by PNG `(EDB88320 & 82608EDB)` and I tried leaving off the length and chunk type with the various polynomials I used before; I also tried including the information before the chunk which defines the PNG signature. I never got 6fb33d9c.

Any ideas on why I can't get the right CRC via calculator?

Comment: First off, you should *not* include the length: ".. including the chunk type field and chunk data fields, but not including the length field" ([PNG Specs, Chunk Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5Chunk-layout)). Also, you need to start with the CRC initialized to `FFFFFFFF` (and finally -- but you never got there -- use the *bitwise inverse*). Alas ... with all this extra information, I can't get your online calculator to work either! You may check [Appendix D-Sample CRC](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#D-CRCAppendix) for a working routine in C.

Comment: Works for me in Java. http://ideone.com/DZnw1A

Comment: The Appendix D sample referenced above is correct. I used that as a starting point in my code and then optimized it.